# Hidden form fields become visible on click

Tags: field, hidden

I have an html mail form where I would like to hide the last five input fields unless the user chooses to be on our mailing list by clicking a radio button or a check box.  Then I would like the hidden fields to become visible.  Is there a simple script for this?

Thanks 
(no code)

Answer (score 0):

you could wrap the last five input fields in a div and define the style to "display: none;" then bind an event to the radio button, when it is clicked set the display to block.

Comment: Right now I have the input fields inside a table - would I make a separate table and keep it inside the form box?

Comment: It's really up to you, you could wrap the whole table inside a div/span and toggle the css-display property accordingly....or if they are part of a much larger table, you could simply wrap each individual input in its own div/span and give them all the same class to provide easy css control...

Comment: So I already have the whole form inside a div.  How would I toggle the CSS to do what you are suggesting?  Would you like to see the Code for the box and the form inside - CSS for the box?

Answer (score 0):

Try looking into the CSS display property.  Set this in Javascript in an onclick event.  Without some code that's about all the help I can give.  Try making a JSFiddle, it doesn't have to be the exact code you're working on, just an example.  If you want a serious, helpful answer, you'll have to provide more info.

Comment: I'm still working on it A.O. may have come up with something.  I might be putting up the code so you could take a look at that when I do.  Thanks so much for your interest.